# Angular JS live select dropdown search filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, full-text-search, html-select

I am grabbing some news items from a newsfeed REST API and have implemented a free text instant search.

I am now trying to implement a search from a dropdown list that works with the same data but I can filter by author. How can I use a dropdown the same way I use a free text search as a filter on the `ng-repeat` so that I can filter the results by author?

### Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ADukg/9506/).

**app.js:**

```
/* Newsfeed API Call */
var app = angular.module('newsFeed', [])
    .controller('Newsfeed', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('https://newsapi.org/v1/articles?source=the-next-web&sortBy=latest&apiKey=6ddf8d3cc8a54cc0abf89ad7d685da54').
        then(function(response) {
            $scope.news = response.data;
            console.log(response.data.articles);
        });
    });
```

**index.html:**

```
<div class="container">
  <br/>
  <form>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Newsfeed</h2>
      <br/>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="searchText" name="search-news" id="search-news" placeholder="Search for news">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <select class="custom-select" ng-controller="Newsfeed">
          <option selected>Filter by Author</option>
          <option ng-repeat="n in news.articles | filter:searchAuthor | unique: 'author'" value="1">{{n.author}}</option>    
        </select>
      </div>        
    </div>
  </form>    

  <div ng-controller="Newsfeed">
    <div class="card" style="width: 20rem;" ng-repeat="n in news.articles | filter:searchText | filter:searchAuthor">
      <img class="card-img-top img-responsive" src="{{n.urlToImage}}" alt="Card image cap">
      <div class="card-block">
        <h4 class="card-title">{{n.title}}</h4>
        <p class="card-text"> {{n.description | cut:true:100:' ...'}}</p>
        <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Mistalis Yeah, see my comment below.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want your `<select>` to filter your `ng-repeat` on articles.

You can use `ng-options` to display values on your `<select>`, and store the selected value in the scope with `ng-model`:

```
<select ng-options="n.author for n in news.articles | unique: 'author'" ng-model="selectedAuthor">
    <option value="" ng-click="selectedAuthor = undefined">Filter by Author</option>
</select>
```

Then, you just have to filter articles on `selectedAuthor`:

```
<div ng-repeat="n in news.articles | filter: searchText | filter: selectedAuthor">
```

### [Working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/ADukg/9516/)

Comment: This doesn't show any options in the dropdown other than the default

Comment: @user3574492 Provide a Fiddle of your code, if will be easier to fix it. :-)

Comment: @user3574492 It works as expected, but you declare `ng-controller="Newsfeed"` in a child div. I moved it to your **container div**, and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Mistalis/ADukg/9516/

Comment: That seems to do it, only thing now is the default select option is not showing, shows a blank value instead and when an option is changed the blank value dissapears

Comment: When I change the author to the default option it should show all right? but it shows nothing. Sorry to be picky

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134096/discussion-between-mistalis-and-user3574492).

Comment: This solution you provided is not working properly, when I change the author from the dropdown it doesn't show all articles for that author (just shows a single one). Also when you change the author and change back to the default option in the dropdown the news items all disappear.

Comment: It happened because `ng-click` does not trigger on select on Chrome (it works on Firefox). [**Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/05go7bd4/3) I use a button to clean the `selectedAuthor` filter.

Comment: Yeah that works fine but even then, when choosing an author from the dropdown, it only shows a single news item for the author when it should show all news items for that author.